# json_encode adding special characters

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Now without having to read boring code let me just summarise what is going on. 
An XHR request goes out via jQuery post function when the document loads. The post sends a POST header to a PHP file that calls another php file to process some strings and return it. Finally an echoed json_encode function returns the string to the jQuery post function which the jQuery then manipulates into the DOM.

The result that is returned by JavaScript's post function is this:

```
<option value="\&quot;auto2\&quot;">auto2&lt;\/option&gt;</option>
```

See all those escape characters? Well I tried just echoing the result on the PHP side instead of `echo`ing with `json_encode` function and it returns:

```
<option value="auto">auto</option>
```

Without any other special characters. This is what is desired. My question is, is this okay to use? And why does `json_encode` add special characters? Is there a way to use `json_encode` without those other characters being returned?

**EDIT**

**JS**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var PROCESSOR_FILE = "http://address/include/processor.php";

    $.post(PROCESSOR_FILE, {"task": "verticalSelect"}, function(data) {
        $("#verticalSelect").html(data);
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
$IMEXporterpath = dirname(__FILE__);
$IMEXporterFile = $IMEXporterpath . "/IMEXporter.class.php";

if (isset($_REQUEST["task"]))
    $task   = $_REQUEST["task"];
else
    $task   = "";


    require_once $IMEXporterFile;
    $IMEXp = new IMEXp();

    $result = $IMEXp->returnHtml($task);
    echo json_encode($result);
```

**MORE PHP**

```
public function returnHtml($element) {
        return $this->returnHtml_HTML($element);
    }


    private function returnHtml_HTML($element) {
        if($element == "verticalSelect") {

            $dbTables   = $this->get_Tables();
            $nbTable    = count($dbTables);

            for ($a = 0; $a < $nbTable; $a++) {
                    $ZHTML  .=  '<option value="'.$dbTables[$a].'">'.$dbTables[$a].'</option>';
            }
        }
        return $ZHTML;
    }
```

Comment: `json_encode` isn't the problem here; you seem to be HTML-encoding it as well, and adding an extra `</option>` in somewhere. So... can we see the code, please?

Comment: So... why do you need json_encode if all you return is a string? can you not just return the string?

Comment: Can you paste the code of the get_Tables() method?

Comment: You aren't returning JSON so why are you JSON encoding it? You are returning an HTML string, so just don't json encode it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On PHP 5.3.13:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain"); // to make sure browser displays raw html
$str = '<option value="auto">auto</option>';

echo json_encode($str);
echo "\n";
echo $str;
```

Outputs

```
"<option value=\"auto\">auto<\/option>"
<option value="auto">auto</option>
```

No converted special chars here.

```
$.post('test.php').done(function(text){
  return console.log(text);
});
```

Prints the same to the console.

Without AJAX does json_encode($str) display `&quot;` etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing some code, it's hard to know what's happening, and maybe I didn't understand your question. In my experience, it's best to put everything in UTF-8. I can't remember exactly, but UTF-8 is the default for AJAX in some situations. Sorry for my vagueness, but there doesn't seem to be a good workaround if you're not using UTF-8.

That means that you should change all the tables in your database to UTF-8, save all your files in UTF-8 format (I use TextPad to change the format), and specify all your HTML pages to UTF-8.

I had to go through that unpleasant experience, because I develop sites in portuguese with a lot of accented characters. I used to try to use ISO-8859-1, but after working more with AJAX, I found that UTF-8 is really the only viable option.

Comment: Well, I actually am encoding everything in DB with UTF-8. I know what you mean, I've experienced problems of my own in the past by omitting encoding. Also, code is now edited in.